# How to return JSON Azure functio app httptrigger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, azure, azure-function-app

I created Azure function app with http trigger which should return JSON file.

Here is part of my nodejs script.

```js
var promise = Promise.all([getFood("first"), getFood("second"), getFood("third")]); 
promise.then(function(data) {
        let res = JSON.stringify(data);

        context.res = {
            body: res
        };
        context.done();
});
```

It returns nothing.

But when I try script with something like this it works:

```js
var promise = Promise.all([getFood("first"), getFood("second"), getFood("third")]); 
promise.then(function(data) {
        let res = JSON.stringify(data);


});

context.res = {
     body:"This is text"
};
context.done();
```

And it will return string in body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
   var data = await Promise.all([getFood("first"), getFood("second"),getFood("third")]); 

   return {
     body: JSON.stringify(data)
   };
}
```